# Is it possible to run PWA inside android/ios native apps?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, caching, progressive-web-apps

Can I get PWA capabilities such as requests caching in native apps for anrdoid/ios (I need some access to native features such as camera and so on)

Or another way to cache requests in ionic 4 + angular 7. Native storage is not the case because of small size limit

I tried to `ng add @angular/pwa`, configure requests caching and then
run `ionic cordova run(or build) android --prod`
. Web version of app - caching works and 
native app - caching doesn't works

I expected to see some cached requrests but I get `TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.` error in console (devtools webview) with device app debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its possible. you can call it inside Web-view
you can use `cordova` libraries for active that

```
npm i ionic-cache
```

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-cache Ionic cache service that can
>   cache almost everything. It caches requests, observables, promises and
>   classic data

and you can move with this its improved one

> https://github.com/localForage/localForage

Comment: can you provide some code? Answer isn't clear to me

Comment: Ye I saw it. I already tried to make it on my own with Native Storage (which is used by this package) but faced with limit of 50 records in it. Will try this one, thanks)